# Singular tags still popping up

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

I've noticed two singular tags lately. One has a bit of usage and the other is brand new:

- [muslim](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim)
- [cigar-bar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cigar-bar)

I know "Muslim" works as noun and adjective but it just doesn't feel right. Would `muslims` or `islam` work any better as tags? Or any other suggestions?

`cigar-bar` doesn't strike me as a good tag in any case. It's too specialized to get much use and too similar to other things to need to separate. Merge into `food-and-drink` or some other tag? Or just re-tag that question?

If you're willing to fight and die to keep it, at least let's make it plural please `cigar-bars` (-;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[muslim](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim) is now a synonym of [islam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam)

[cigar-bar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cigar-bar) is a synonym of [nightlife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nightlife) now (I agree cigar-bar as a standalone tag is not good.)

Answer (score 0):

[muslim](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim) should go. Better make it a synonym to [religion](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion), which should be sufficient. Cigar bars.. not sure. Perhaps [nightlife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nightlife) would be a better fit?

Comment: Yes I wasn't sure if people also go to cigar bars in the day? I did also think muslim might work as part of a broader religion tag. But we have good islam-specific questions and considering that people think languages should have individual tags here I would be surprised if they also wanted to group all religions together `\-:`